# What is the Identity of a convolution layer in a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, cross-correlation, convolution

I wanted to know what the identity of a convolutional layer of a neural network was. For standard convolution operation in mathematics the identity is the delta function, however, convolutions in neural networks is **discrete** and has **biases** in them and can have arbitrary stride and are applied to tensors (of images) usually.

Despite those facts can a single convolutional layer with biases, have something equivalent/similar to an identity operation? Something easy to express as a (fake) tensor image or something like that?

---

Some thoughts:

I know that at least for simple matrices (no tensors) and the input is a 1D vector, the convolution can be expressed as some type of block-diagonal matrix. Having biases just means the last column is just a column of constants equal to the same bias. Thus, it seems simple for single filter, one can always try to compute pseudo-inverses (and I assume pseudo-inverses too) of some sort using SVDs or something like that. However, that doesn't seem to be as clean as just a delta function (e.g. a vector with a single entry of 1). Does something clean like that exist in general? In particular, at least for stride 1 and biases present in the layer?

---

Actually I want something more like:

$\| W_{conv} \star I \| = \| W_{conv} \|$

that preserves the norm of the filters of that conv layer.

Comment: A convolution by itself may as well be htought of as a unfolded vector multiplication, so if you have a 3x3 filter $F$ and image patch $X$, then the result of the convolution is $F\cdot X+b$. As you're mapping from a 3x3 space to a number, it doesn't make sense to talk about identity. Unless you instead use a filter of all 1's and just multiply the matrix $X$ pointwise (i.e, without the secondary step of summing all entries).

Comment: Since you're speaking of inverses, the most practical such convolutional inverse is deconvolution: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers

Comment: @AlexR. I thought about it a bit more and I want something more of the lines of this $\| W_{conv} \star I \| = | W_{conv} \|$, so it preserves the norm of the filters.

Comment: Do you have an application in mind?

Comment: @AlexR. I am simply curious to pass the equivalent of an "empty image" through the convnet (to see the how big the whole process is, more or less).

Comment: So assuming you pad the input image (otherwise your output will be of smaller dimension), then the identity convolution would be a filter that  has a 1 in the top left, and zeros elsewhere. This will do nothing to each cell of the image.

Comment: @AlexR. what about the fact that images have channels and conv layers have biases?

Comment: So if there's a bias then yea, you'd have to do some form of SVD, and most likely the value of the top-left of the convolution will be one that minimizes the square error between all image value minus the bias. With different channels, you're out of luck as most types of convolutions will contract dimensions to a single one.

Comment: @AlexR. sorry meant to say convolutional layers after the and, I corrected my comment.

Comment: Could you expand upon your "empty image" comment. What is it exactly that you're after? As I suspect the above might not be helpful for your goal

Comment: I want to be able to compute the norm of the forward pass without actually passing in an image. The image is just a dummy variable for the forward propagation of the forward pass to work. Sort of trying to compute $\| f \|_{\mathcal H} $